# NullPointerException with IResourceSetProvider?

Tags: java, eclipse, xtext, emf, ecore

I have an Xtext project with an issue I can't seem to solve. Consider the following code:

```
@Inject
IResourceSetProvider resourceSetProvider;

private void function(){
     IProject project = file.getProject();

     URI uri = URI.createPlatformResourceURI(file.getFullPath().toString(), true);
     ResourceSet resourceSet = resourceSetProvider.get(project);
     Resource resource = resourceSet.getResource(uri, true);
}
```

The object "file" is an IFile passed as an argument of this function and is not null, as I am able to access its contents and even print them out as strings, for example. I can also access its IProject field and perform operations on it. However, I'm getting a NullPointerException on the ResourceSet line, namely on the ".get(project)" function. What could cause a NullPointerException to occur at this step, given that said project is definitely not null?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think you need to provide the a reduced enclosing class, imports, etc

Comment: Apologies... I appreciate you trying to help, but I can't seem to fix this. You were right about the resourceSetProvider being null, so something is failing in the injection...

I failed to mention this block of code I showed is inside a class, if relevant.

Comment: Well, I managed to solve it by removing the injection altogether and instancing an IResourceSetProvider manually.


`IResourceSetProvider rs1 = IResourceServiceProvider.Registry.INSTANCE.getResourceServiceProvider(uri).get(IResourceSetProvider.class);`

Comment: I am glad you worked it out. If it is not too much could accept the answer?

Comment: Sure thing! Thanks for the help! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either project is null or the injection failed and the provider is null. You say variable project is not null. Then injection failed.

Comment: I'm sorry... not sure I'm following. How can an injection fail?

Comment: Given the code you provided these are the only options in this line. The injection fails if the osgi container does not recognize your class during the scanning/injection phase as injectable

Comment: @sentient_6, it is important that you create instances of enclosing type via injection.